# invite facebook friends to play together

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i am working on multiplayer unity game and i need to invite my friends to play game with me.
when i use  FB.AppRequest it will request to facebook app and by clicking it it will be redirected to game

I want a callback in game if another user is requesting him/her

any help is welcome.
thank you

Comment: can anyone tell me why it is marked minus?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using facebook plugin. As far as I understand, you want to check any request sent to current user, right?

In general, you should read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2) document that covers most information you should know about requests.

But in short, you need `FB.API` method. You can read more about this method on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.API).

As example (C#):

```
var endpoint = "/me/apprequests";
var method = HttpMethod.GET;
var formData = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "fields", "object, action_type, application, created_time, data, from, id, message, to" } };
FB.API(endpoint, method, callback, formData);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but i want to check that request in my app , while player is online and not in facebook application notification.